# getDistanceFrom Vs distanceFromLocation

Tags: iphone

I'm having a problem with getDistanceFrom and distanceFromLocation. getDistanceFrom is deprecated iOS 4.1 and distanceFromLocation is not available in 3.1.3, how do I get around this problem.

Has anyone else come across this problem ?

My code at the moment is:

```
CLLocationDistance kilometers;
        if ([currentLocation respondsToSelector: @selector(distanceFromLocation:)])
        {
            kilometers = [currentLocation distanceFromLocation:previousLocation] / 1000;
        }
        else
        {
            //kilometers = [currentLocation getDistanceFrom:previousLocation] / 1000;
            kilometers = [currentLocation performSelector: @selector(getDistanceFrom:) withObject: previousLocation] / 1000;
        }
```

Depending on which iOS I compile with I'm getting 'invalid operands to binary' on the lines:

```
kilometers = [currentLocation distanceFromLocation:previousLocation] / 1000;
            kilometers = [currentLocation performSelector: @selector(getDistanceFrom:) withObject: previousLocation] / 1000;
```

Regards,
Stephen

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a [blog post](http://0xced.blogspot.com/2010/09/cllocation-getdistancefrom-vs.html) by Cédric Luthi which has a pretty good solution to this.

In short, you need to enter the following into your main.m and make sure to `#import <objc/runtime.h>` :

```
Method getDistanceFrom = class_getInstanceMethod([CLLocation class], @selector(getDistanceFrom:));
class_addMethod([CLLocation class], @selector(distanceFromLocation:), method_getImplementation(getDistanceFrom), method_getTypeEncoding(getDistanceFrom));
```

You can then use `distanceFromLocation:` on any OS.

Comment: Excellent solution!  Thanks for bringing it to my attention!

Comment: It returns empty ... Please help.
I am checking on 3.0

Thanks in advance

Comment: Also make sure to #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

Answer (score 11):

I use my own method. It is MUCH faster and can be used on both iOS 3.x and iOS 4.x.

```
- (double)distanceFrom:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)locationA to:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)locationB

{
    double R = 6368500.0; // in meters

    double lat1 = locationA.latitude*M_PI/180.0;
    double lon1 = locationA.longitude*M_PI/180.0;
    double lat2 = locationB.latitude*M_PI/180.0;
    double lon2 = locationB.longitude*M_PI/180.0;

    return acos(sin(lat1) * sin(lat2) + 
                cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) *
                cos(lon2 - lon1)) * R;
}
```

Comment: Is it really faster? I didn't notice it being faster than .distanceFromLocation method. The only difference was quite different result values.

Comment: @yerassyl The answer is 5 years old – things may change :) If you make some performance testing, please comment out!